# NGINX load balancing using ip_hash directive

Tags: nginx, load-balancing

I have a simple two node server cluster, running on `localhost:8001` and `localhost:8002`, load-balanced using NGINX. Below is the http context of my `nginx.conf`.

```
http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    upstream backend {
        ip_hash;
        server localhost:8001;
        server localhost:8002;
    }

    log_format upstreamlog 'upstream: $upstream_addr: $request upstream-response-status: $upstream_status';

    server {
        listen              80;
        listen              [::]:80;
        server_name         localhost;
        access_log  logs/access.log  upstreamlog;

        location / {
            proxy_pass http://backend/;
        }
    }
}
```

Initially all requests to http://localhost/ were redirected to upstream server running at port 8001.

--Logs

```
 upstream: [::1]:8001: GET / HTTP/1.1 upstream-response-status: 200
 upstream: [::1]:8001: GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1 upstream-response-status: 200
 upstream: [::1]:8001: GET / HTTP/1.1 upstream-response-status: 200
 upstream: [::1]:8001: GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1 upstream-response-status: 200
 upstream: [::1]:8001: GET / HTTP/1.1 upstream-response-status: 200
 upstream: [::1]:8001: GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1 upstream-response-status: 200
 upstream: [::1]:8001: GET / HTTP/1.1 upstream-response-status: 200
 upstream: [::1]:8001: GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1 upstream-response-status: 200
 ----
 upstream: [::1]:8001: GET / HTTP/1.1 upstream-response-status: 200
 upstream: [::1]:8001: GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1 upstream-response-status: 200
 upstream: [::1]:8001: GET / HTTP/1.1 upstream-response-status: 200
 upstream: [::1]:8001: GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1 upstream-response-status: 200
 upstream: [::1]:8001: GET / HTTP/1.1 upstream-response-status: 200
 upstream: [::1]:8001: GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1 upstream-response-status: 200
 upstream: [::1]:8001: GET / HTTP/1.1 upstream-response-status: 200
 upstream: [::1]:8001: GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1 upstream-response-status: 200
```

Now for testing the fail-over of this setup, I stopped the server running at port 8001. But the fail-over did not work and all subsequent requests were also forwarded to the server at port 8001.

--Logs

```
 upstream: [::1]:8001: GET / HTTP/1.1 upstream-response-status: -
 upstream: [::1]:8001: GET / HTTP/1.1 upstream-response-status: -
 upstream: [::1]:8001: GET / HTTP/1.1 upstream-response-status: -
 upstream: [::1]:8001: GET / HTTP/1.1 upstream-response-status: -
 upstream: [::1]:8001: GET / HTTP/1.1 upstream-response-status: -
 upstream: [::1]:8001: GET / HTTP/1.1 upstream-response-status: -
 upstream: [::1]:8001: GET / HTTP/1.1 upstream-response-status: -
 ----
 upstream: [::1]:8001: GET / HTTP/1.1 upstream-response-status: -
 upstream: [::1]:8001: GET / HTTP/1.1 upstream-response-status: -
 upstream: [::1]:8001: GET / HTTP/1.1 upstream-response-status: -
 upstream: [::1]:8001: GET / HTTP/1.1 upstream-response-status: -
 ----
 upstream: [::1]:8001: GET / HTTP/1.1 upstream-response-status: -
 upstream: [::1]:8001: GET / HTTP/1.1 upstream-response-status: -
 upstream: [::1]:8001, 127.0.0.1:8001, [::1]:8002: GET / HTTP/1.1 upstream-response-status: 504, 504, 200
```

NGINX took a long time, approximately 3 minutes, for switching over to the other node at port 8002. What is that I am missing in the configuration? I know that default `max_fails` is `1` and `fail_timeout` is `10 seconds`. How to make NGINX switch-over to other server node with zero downtime?

(NOTE: `ip_hash` had to be used for session affinity and other purposes)

Comment: This is a [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com) question as it pertains to infrastructure.

Comment: @tadman Thanks for the heads up. I will try to post future infra question on SF

Comment: Have posted the same at SF https://serverfault.com/questions/891666/nginx-load-balancing-using-ip-hash-directive